# WCF XML & JSON support using a single OperationContract method?

Tags: wcf

I was trying to work on the following requirement for days. I would like my WCF API to handle XML and JSON requests/responses using a single method. I also know that .net 4 supports automaticformat selection but it does not work the way i want my XML & JSON structures to be. Here are my structures:

JSON:

```
{
  "response": {
    "timestamp": "12.00AM",    
    "locations": {
      "location": [        
        {
          "id": "5",
          "name": "hello world",
          "statusid": "8"
        }
      ]
    },
    "errorcode": "444"
  }
}
```

XML:

```
<response>
    <timestamp>12.00AM</timestamp>
    <locations>
        <location>
            <id>5</id>
            <name>hello world</name>
            <statusid>8</statusid>
        </location>
    </locations>
    <errorcode>444</errorcode>
</response>
```

I have tried toggling the value of "BodyStyle" in my OperationContract, e.g. for JSON i have to put WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped and for XML i have to put WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare to work according to the above structures. Since i want to be able to use one OperationContract and automatically respond with XML/JSON structures depending on the Content-Type, what changes/additions do i have to make? Is there a way to set this BodyStyle using Code for both XML and JSON (P.S. API should be the way it is and should not be able pass any parameters like getvalue/{xml})?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: below is my OperationContract:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "PushNotify")]       
        ResponsePushNotify PushNotify(RequestPushNotifiy pushnotify);
```

Here is the DataContract:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Test: ITest
    {
    responsePushNotify = new ResponsePushNotify();
       ResponsePushNotify PushNotify(RequestPushNotifiy pushnotify)
    {
        if (Content-Type == "application/json; charset=utf-8")  
            {  
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));  
            }  
    responsePushNotify.id = "1";
    responsePushNotify.value = "Hello World";

    return responsePushNotify ;
    }
```

Here's the suggested code:

```
public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override IDispatchMessageFormatter GetReplyDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            WebGetAttribute webGet = operationDescription.Behaviors.Find<WebGetAttribute>();
            IDispatchMessageFormatter json = null, xml = null;
            WebMessageFormat originalFormat = webGet.ResponseFormat;
            webGet.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            json = base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            webGet.ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            xml = base.GetReplyDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
            webGet.ResponseFormat = originalFormat;
            return new MyReplyDispatchMessageFormatter(json, xml);
        }
    }
    public class MyReplyDispatchMessageFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
    {
        IDispatchMessageFormatter jsonFormatter;
        IDispatchMessageFormatter xmlFormatter;
        public MyReplyDispatchMessageFormatter(IDispatchMessageFormatter jsonFormatter, IDispatchMessageFormatter xmlFormatter)
        {
            this.jsonFormatter = jsonFormatter;
            this.xmlFormatter = xmlFormatter;
        }
        public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Used for replies only");
        }

        public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
        {
            IDispatchMessageFormatter formatter = this.xmlFormatter;
            if (OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.ContainsKey(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                WebBodyFormatMessageProperty webBody = (WebBodyFormatMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name];
                if (webBody != null && webBody.Format == WebContentFormat.Json)
                {
                    formatter = this.jsonFormatter;
                }
            }

            return formatter.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
        }
    }
```

Here's my webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior" name="Service.Test">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Services.ITest" bindingConfiguration="general"/>
      </service>      
    </services>  
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="general" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="4194304"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"  />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>     
    <behaviors>      
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>         
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>       
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>       
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel> 
</configuration>
```

So now my problem is, how do i define my custom behavior in code and add it to webconfig? What changes do i need to do? Also if i were to set "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped" How & Where do i do that?

Comment: You might have to write your your own customdispatcher. Refer the below link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/04640a45-1a37-4722-8ed7-9f75c155dc14

Comment: That's great Rajesh :) But i need to set WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped especially. How would i accomplish that Rajesh?

Comment: @carlosfigueira: i have done what you have mentioned in the post and added the exact same classes as follows:

public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior  
  
public class MyReplyDispatchMessageFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter  
    
        public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)  
        
        public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)

Comment: Sorry this doesnt allow me to post all code at once. Below is my operation contract:

[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Push")]        
        Response Push(Request pushnotifi);

Here is my data contract:

Response Push(Request pushnotifi)
{
if (requestHeader.ContentType == "application/json; charset=utf-8")
{
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
}

return response;
}

Comment: @carlosfigueira: im not allowed to post code here says its too long and its quite frustrating unless i answer my own question. Is there a way i could contact you? email or something? Because there is loads to put here and since im new to stackoverflow its limited.

Comment: You can edit your *question* to add the code - I agree that code in the comments don't work too well.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I have updated my question accordingly. Please check. Thank you for your great time.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question posted very long time ago but may be this will be useful for somebody. I found solution on overcoder.net. All you need is to generate correspondent strings for desired output format and use Stream for result type.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "test?format={format}")]
System.IO.Stream test(string format);
```

```
public System.IO.Stream test(string format)
{
     ArrayList ar = new ArrayList() { 1, 2, 3 };
     if (format == "text")
         result = String.Join(",", ar.ToArray());
     if (format == "xml")
     { 
        result = @"<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <result>";
        foreach (int i in ar)
            result += String.Format("\r\n        <item>{0}</item>", i);
        result += @"
      </result>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
     }
     if (format == "json")
         result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ar, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

     OutgoingWebResponseContext context = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
     context.ContentType = "text/plain";
     return new System.IO.MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(result));
}
```